# Resource at '/bin/page3' not found: No resource found

Tags: aem

I'm trying to create a simple servlet class in aem
using ajax call

I'm getting errors like this:

> Resource at '/bin/page3' not found: No resource found
>   RequestURI=/bin/page3
>
> Servlet= /apps/sling/servlet/errorhandler/404.html

Comment: Did you try to delete /bin from CRXDE and deploy your code , then check it again?

Comment: What is your question..? Showing your code might help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the servlet code which you are trying to run, as it looks like there is some issue with your code and it is not getting active. You can also search for your servlet in this path (http://localhost:4502/system/console/components) and see whether it is active or not?